# Pagination not working with XSLTViewWebpart when created using Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, xslt-list-view-web-part, paging

I am having similar issue as mentioned in below URL's.

[Paging in XsltListViewWebPart is not working perfectly when added programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/paging-in-xsltlistviewwebpart-is-not-working-perfectly-when-added-programmatical)

[Why don't folders work when adding an XsltListViewWebPart to the page via code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/why-dont-folders-work-when-adding-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-to-the-page-via-code?rq=1)

However when I try to use SaveChanges `$webpartmanager.SaveChanges($lvwp)`, am getting '

> Object Reference not set to an instance of Object

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
# Check if the page already exists
$currentPage = $publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages() | Where { $_.Url -eq $pageUrl}

CheckOutPage -spFile $currentPage.ListItem.File -allowUndoCheckout $false

$webPartProperty_Visible = $true  
$web = get-spweb $siteUrl  
$defaultPage = $web.GetFile($pageUrl)  

# Get the LimitedWebPartManager  
$webpartmanager=$defaultPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)  
 #Deleting existing web part
foreach ($webpart in ($webpartmanager.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $viewName}))
{
    write-host $siteUrl +": Existing Web part - " + $webpart.Title + " : " + $webpart.ID        
    $webpartmanager.DeleteWebPart($webpartmanager.WebParts[$webpart.ID])
    break;
}
#Create fancy GUID  
$lvwpGuid1 = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()  
$lvwpKey = "g_" + $lvwpGuid1.Replace("-","_")  

# Instantiate wp  
$lvwp = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart   
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$lvwp.ListId = $list.ID
#$lvwp.ViewGuid =  $list.Views[$viewName].ID.ToString(); 
$lvwp.Toolbar = "Summary"
$lvwp.ID = $lvwpKey  
$code = "$" 
$lvwp.Title = $viewName   
$lvwp.Visible = $webPartProperty_Visible   
$lvwp.ChromeType = [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType]::TitleOnly; 
$lvwp.HorizontalAlign = "Center" 
$lvwp.JSLink = $jsLink
# Set the view  
$lvwp.ViewGuid = $list.Views[$viewName].ID.ToString();  

# Add the web part  
$webpartmanager.AddWebPart($lvwp, $addContentTo, $positionOnPage);  
Write-Host $lvwp
$webpartmanager.SaveChanges($lvwp)

CheckInPage -spFile $currentPage.ListItem.File

$web.Update();  
$web.Dispose()
```

Only difference I see is URL's are using Server Side Object Model and I am trying same thing in Powershell.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Got a hint from this 
[How to add a listviewwebpart by code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103227/how-to-add-a-listviewwebpart-by-code)

AddWebPart doesn't require SaveChanges call, so I called another function after adding all the webparts to SaveChanges and it helped.

```
function SaveChanges($siteUrl, $pageUrl,$viewName)
{
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
$publishingWeb =   
 [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
# Check if the page already exists
$currentPage = $publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages() | Where { $_.Url -eq $pageUrl}

CheckOutPage -spFile $currentPage.ListItem.File -allowUndoCheckout $false

$webPartProperty_Visible = $true  
$web = get-spweb $siteUrl  
$defaultPage = $web.GetFile($pageUrl)  

# Get the LimitedWebPartManager  
$webpartmanager = $defaultPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)  
 #Deleting existing web part
foreach ($webpart in ($webpartmanager.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $viewName}))
{
    write-host $siteUrl +"Saving WebPart" + $webpart.Title + " : " + $webpart.ID        
    $webpartmanager.SaveChanges($webPart)
    break;
}
CheckInPage -spFile $currentPage.ListItem.File

$web.Update(); 

$web.Dispose()
}
```